# Transparent disk and memory response caching in volley library android

Tags: android, memory, android-volley

I am new to volley library. I just begin with it reading [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). 
I found three features that volley library offers but couldn't understand what exactly those mean and how those are used.

1. Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP cache coherence.
2. Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.
3. Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with data fetched asynchronously from the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android volley is a networking library was introduced to make networking calls much easier, faster without writing tons of code. By default all the volley network calls works asynchronously, so we don’t have to worry about using asynctask anymore.

Volley comes with lot of features. Some of them are

1. Request queuing and prioritization
2. Effective request cache and memory management
3. Extensibility and customization of the library to our needs
4. Cancelling the requests